# Hosting a WCF service with Net.TCP

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I am totally new to this and trying to host the simplest WCF service with a net.tcp binding
I have Windows 7 Professional and IIS7 and have enabled NON http activation.

- I start a new WCF Service application
  project in vs2010 and compile it.
  NOHTING ELSE!
- I delete all my IIS
  Websites and add a new called WCFHost
- I open up WcfTestClient.exe and adds
  http://localhost/Service1.svc the application finds it

The Web.config looks like this (untouched)

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

So far, so good. But what about that net.tcp binding. I add the "enabledProtocols" attribute so my applicationHost.config looks like this

```
       <site name="WCFHOST" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="WCFHOST" enabledProtocols="http,net.tcp,net.pipe,net.msmq">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Prosjekter\temp\TestService\TestService" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="808:*" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Then I go to the IIS WCFHost website and add binding net.tcp 808:*
And then I modify my web.config for the WCF Service to look like this. (just changed the binding on the endpoints)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

When I now try to add the service net.tcp://localhost:808/Service1.svc in my WcfTestClient.exe I get the error

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost/Service1.svc 
TCP-errorcode 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.... 127.0.0.1:808

My firewall is turned off. 
I have seen one thing, though.. when using netstat -a the 808 port is not listed there.. should it?

Can someone help me just creating my first WCF service with nettcp binding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The net.tcp bindings are enabled on IIS for requests on 808?
Check it on IIS manager / bindings.

[See it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188618/enabling-net-tcp)

Comment: Thanks a million! I've struggled with this all day :)

Answer (score 13):

As Tocco says, check that the service is running. You can do this by checking:

> netstat /an | find /i "808 "

And it should show:

> TCP    0.0.0.0:808            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
>    TCP    [::]:808               [::]:0                 LISTENING

if the service is running correctly.

To get it to start if it's not already working, you can issue:

> sc start NetTcpActivator

from the command line to ttry to start it.

Even before that, make sure that [the non-HTTP activation windows components are installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx).

Also check that the services are actually running.  [I had a problem where they would not necessarily start after a reboot.](https://superuser.com/questions/295454/net-tcp-listener-adapter-and-net-tcp-port-sharing-service-not-starting-on-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and resolved it by not only creating a TCP binding on the site as follows:

[image: IIS Site Bindings]

But also enabling the `net.tcp` protocol in Advanced Settings:

[image]