# TCP Federation and ADFS

Tags: wif

I hope someone can help me out.  How can I do federation over TCP?  I am using ADFS as my STS.  My WCF service (Relying party) expose its endpoint over net.tcp bindings.  The STS would be accessed through wsHttp endpoints.  How would I do this? Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am just wondering if I am doing this correctly. I have created a custom binding. This is for the server side.

```
<!-- STS Binding -->
<ws2007HttpBinding>
 <binding name="STSBinding">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows">
    <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
      </transport>
     <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
    algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
   </security>
  </binding>
</ws2007HttpBinding>

<customBinding>
<binding name="WCFTestServiceLibrary.IService1_FederationNetTcpBinding">
<security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
<secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="IssuedToken">
<issuedTokenParameters tokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-  1.1#SAMLV2.0">
  <issuer address="https://test/adfs/services/trust/13/issuedtokenmixedasymmetricbasic256"
   binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSBinding">
  </issuer>
  <issuerMetadata address="https://test/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
  <claimTypeRequirements>
  <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" isOptional="true" />
  <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" isOptional="true" />
  </claimTypeRequirements>
  </issuedTokenParameters>
  </secureConversationBootstrap>
  </security>
  <binaryMessageEncoding  />
  <tcpTransport  />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never done this but from what I've read:

Check that your endpoint is enabled in ADFS.

Then add tcp to the "Enabled Protocols" for the ADFS IIS site.

Refer [Enabling net.tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188618/enabling-net-tcp)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.  I have also wrote custom binding.