# can I enable net.tcp programmatically or scriptwise?

Tags: iis

Based on [Enabling net.tcp in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188618/enabling-net-tcp)

can I either check for or enable this protocol without iis manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can use appcmd (located in \windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd):

```
appcmd set APP "Default Web Site/AppName" /enabledProtocols:http,net.pipe
```

Note that you need to list all protocols that you want to be enabled.