# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeTcpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

My Web.Config is here:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig"/>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="testService.RaptorAPI">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="testService.IRaptorAPI" listenUriMode="Explicit"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="testService.IRaptorAPI" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://ccs-labs.com:802"/>
        <add baseAddress="http://ccs-labs.com:801"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

**Update 1**
net.tcp is bound on IIS, The appropriate services are running.

---

Can someone find and correct the error "**Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].**"

Answer (score 4):

Please try these steps

1. Go to Server Manager > Features > Add Features. Here enable **WCF Activation** feature. Version of .NET Framework can vary on Windows version.

[image]

2. In **IIS** find your **website**, navigate to Advanced Settings and update Enabled Protocols to "http,net.tcp".

[image]

3. In **IIS** find your **website**, check your bindings for net.tcp port.

[image]

4. Make sure you are not using **IIS Express**, because Express version does not support non-HTTP protocols.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your TCP is not enabled. The below post may help you find the solution. 
[Enabling net.tcp in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188618/enabling-net-tcp)