# How to test WCF net.tcp when http works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service setup in IIS.  I can browse fine to the HTTP endpoint (http://localhost with no port#) in a web browser.

My app is using net.tcp//localhost:51056. I keep getting an error about

> The message could not be dispatched because the service at the
>   endpoint address xxx is unavailable for the protocol of the address.

The exception is a

> EndpointNotFoundException

net.tcp is setup for the service in IIS.

There is no way to test a net.tcp endpoint that I'm aware of.  This use to work.  Any ideas how I can trouble shoot what is wrong?

Comment: Can you telnet to the endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.  At the commend prompt, I type in "telnet <machine-name> 51056".  I get a blank screen.

Comment: That means the connection works. What does http://localhost:51056 do in the browser?

Comment: The page can't be displayed.

Comment: I would set up tracing to see what is really going on in details.

Comment: Tracing details don't add anything.  I see entries where the app is trying to call methods on the service but the throw the same EndpointNotFoundException.  So not additional info.

Answer (score 0):

if http is working and net.tcp not. you may want to setup/check setup net.tcp binding at IIS level. take look at
[Enabling net.tcp in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188618/enabling-net-tcp)