# IIS net.tcp binding not available

Tags: c#, .net, iis

We received a new application server and I just installed IIS and Web Deploy.
While configuring a new site, I noticed that I can't add a `net.tcp` binding.

Only `http` and `https` are available.

What do I have to do so that `net.tcp` is available from the dropdown list?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything online.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have "Net.Tcp Listener Adapter" service running?

Comment: It is already answered here: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188618/enabling-net-tcp"

Comment: The Net.Tcp Listener Adapter is not available in the Services. I've tried installing SMSvcHost.exe but it still isn't available.. how can I add this service?

Comment: it didnt work with setting the Enabled Protocols to http,net.tcp